# Jumpy cursor on Gateway NV55C with Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad

My new laptop suddenly got this jumpy cursor, after 1 day of use.

What could be the cause? And fix?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a mouse? When this happened to me, it was a sign of imminent mouse failure.

Answer (score 0):

I researched this as well and found one type of solution, function (Fn) + F6, disables completely, then do the same to re-enable when finished typing.